# Что такое потокобезопасность C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Что такое потокобезопасность? Как потоки могут влиять друг на друга таким образом, что они сломаются? Как обезопасить себя от подобных поломок?

Comment: Потоки не сломаются. Просто разработчики не всегда пишут код так, что он работает корректно при вызове из нескольких потоков одновременно

Comment: Самый простой пример - напишите код, который увеличивает значение поля объекта на 1. И подумайте что будет, если этот код будет выполняться одновременно в нескольких потоках для одного и того же объекта

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Вот пример.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int count = 0;
    var task1 = Task.Run(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            count++;
        }
    });
    var task2 = Task.Run(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            count++;
        }
    });
    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
    Console.WriteLine(count);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Какой вывод в консоль ожидается? `1000`, верно?

Запускаю

```
1000
```

Вроде все ок, ну-ка еще разок

```
998
```

Опа. Вот потоки и поругались, а в чем собственно дело.

**Непредсказуемость результата выполнения многопоточного кода означает, что код не является потокобезопасным.**

А в том что `count++` это на самом деле `count = count + 1`, то есть процессор должен сначала прочитать значение переменной, затем прибавить к нему единицу, затем записать в эту переменную обратно. То есть не одно действие, а несколько.

Представьте, что действия двумя потоками выполняются во времени в следующем порядке.

- Поток 1 читает значение 10 и прибавляет к нему 1, получает 11
- Поток 2 читает значение 10 и прибавляет к нему 1, получает 11
- Поток 1 записывает значение 11 в переменную
- Поток 2 записывает значение 11 в переменную

В итоге единицу добавляли 2 раза, должно получиться 12, а получается 11.

Исправить просто - использовать потокобезопасный `Increment`.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int count = 0;
    var task1 = Task.Run(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
        }
    });
    var task2 = Task.Run(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref count);
        }
    });
    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
    Console.WriteLine(count);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод

```
1000
```

И 1000 всегда.

Для более сложных операций есть так называемые примитивы синхронизации, например `lock`, когда вам надо, чтобы определенный участок кода выполнялся одновременно только во одном потоке, а остальные потоки ждали. И много других примитивов, чтобы управлять потокобезопасностью. Я лишь показал наглядный пример. У синхронизации потоков при обеспечении потокобезопасности есть новый подводный камень, который вас ждет, и называется он дедлок (deadlock). Но не спешите постить новый вопрос про дедлоки, материалов в сети на эту тему полно.

Comment: Без `Thread.Sleep(1);` вероятность поломки намного выше.

Comment: @Qwertiy верно, но я пытался создать ситуацию, когда поломка происходит не в 100% случаев.

Comment: Оказывается, нет. https://ideone.com/RoqGYd - на меньших значениях что-то оно вполне успешно отрабатывает о_О То ли что-то поменялось, то ли линукс, то ли процессор одноядерный у них там... Я насколько помню, sleep перед инкрементом уменьшал вероятность поломки, а что-то на ideone не воспроизводится :(

Comment: @Qwertiy от пула зависит, как он отреагирует. Таски просто могут стартануть с большой разбежкой во времени и первый закончится когда еще второй не начался.