# С#, потоки, максимальная нагрузка

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Не очень понимаю механизм работы потоков. Мне казалось, что каждому запущенному потоку выделяется определенное количество памяти и каждый поток работает со своей скоростью, чтобы не мешать главному. То есть какую бы сложную операцию в дополнительном потоке мы не делали, главный поток тормозить не будет. Это не так ?
У меня такой код дико вешает фпс. Но как тогда выносить в поток дорогостоящие операции, если из-за них падает фпс ?

```
float _testSec = 0;
public override void _Process(double delta)
{
    _testSec -= (float)delta;
    if (_testSec < 0 ) 
    {
        _testSec = 1f;

        ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(ThreadFunction);
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadStart);
        thread.Start();
    }
}

public void ThreadFunction ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        float f = Mathf.Sqrt (i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы запускаете по новому потоку каждую секунду, что ли? Ну тогда логично будет ожидать, что однажды потоков станет настолько много, что процессор перестанет справляться с нагрузкой

Comment: _пройдите полноценную регистрацию аккаунта_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На запуск нового потока тоже тратится куча ресурсов, поэтому потоки лучше использовать из пула.

Если по-простому, то запуск нового потока лучше производить так, особенно это скажется на производительности, если нужно запускать много недолго работающих потоков.

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => ThreadFunction());
```

Если нужна пара потоков, работающих длительное время, то можно использовать и `Thread` напрямую без пула.

А количество одновременно активно работающих потоков не должно превышать количество ядер процессора, у множенное на 2.

```
int maxCount = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2;
```

В противном случае будет потребляться много слишком процессорного времени на переключение между потоками.

Для эффективного распределения работы между потоками научитесь пользоваться следующими инструментами:

1. Комбинаторы - `Task.WhenAll`, `Task.WhenAny`, потребуются базовые знания про асинхронное программирование `async/await`.
2. Примитивы синхронизации, например `SemaphoreSlim`.
3. Шаблон проектирования Producer/Consumer.
4. Общие понимания о потокобезопасности и работы с потокобезопасными коллекциями.
5. Навыки разрешения проблем типа "гонка потоков" (race condition) или "дедлок" (deadlock).

В целом многопоточность - это весьма обширная тема для изучения. И утверждение "чем больше потоков - тем лучше" вообще не соответствует действительности.

Если же вникать в глубины многопоточного программирования пока страшно, начните с 1-2 потоков с параллельными вычислениями, научитесь безопасно передавать им данные и так же безопасно их забирать.

Почитайте:

- [задача об обедающих философах C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1219461/373567)
- [Thread'ы, Task'и, async'и, await'ы в C# под WPF на .NET Framework 4.8](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1250881/373567)
- [Потокобезопасные списки C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1261353/373567)
- [Что такое потокобезопасность C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1350877/373567)
- [Массовые асинхронные вызовы с ограничением на количество параллельных без семафора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303748/373567)

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробный ответ! Как раз читаю про пул, попробовала сделать так : ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadFunction); Тормоза ушли, все хорошо. Это тоже нормальный вариант или лучше использовать Task из вашего примера ? Пошла читать про остальные термины )

Comment: @Екатерина `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ThreadFunction);` да, так тоже можно. `Task.Run` его же использует внутри себя, только еще возвращает удобный для ожидания `Task`.

Comment: спасибо, ответ суперполезен

Comment: лучше использовать Task, и только если когда-то их не хватит вытащить из чулана Thread @Екатерина